# How upload images synchronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await

I try to delay showing images until all of them be uploaded (in the browser), but my code goes on (doesnt't wait for uploading).

I'm using promises and async-await. Here is my code:

```
async _renderPhotos(data){
    console.log("step6.1");
    const photoSetDiv = document.createElement("div");
    photoSetDiv.classList.add("photoSet");
    // photoSetDiv.classList.add("unvisible");
    photoSetDiv.id=`photoSet${this._step}`;
    const urlArray=data.map( image => image.url);

    await this._uploadAllImages(data, photoSetDiv);
    console.log("step6.3");
    this._container.appendChild(photoSetDiv);

}

 _uploadAllImages(array, container){
    var index=0;

    //upload each of the images is  separate promise
    function checkImage(item){new Promise ((resolve, reject) =>{

        //Creating <figure>, <img> and <div>.
        const figure = document.createElement("figure");
        figure.classList.add(item.site);
        const title = document.createElement("div");
        title.classList.add("titleImage");
        title.innerHTML =`#${item.site}`;
        figure.appendChild(title);
        const img = new Image();
        img.classList.add("image");

        img.onload=() => {
            console.log("step 6.2");
            const classCSS=figureClass(index);
            figure.classList.add(classCSS);
            figure.appendChild(img);
            container.appendChild(figure);
            index ++;
            resolve(item)}

        img.src=item.url;
        // Event on the image: after clicking on the image it is erlarged
        img.onclick= () => {
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalImg.src=item.url;
        };
    })};

    return  Promise.all(array.map(checkImage));
}
```

I want to wait for uploading images. Equivalent: 
display in the console in the following order:
step 6.1
step 6.2 (many times because of many images)
step 6.3

Comment: You aren't returning your promise from `checkImage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the pitfalls of `await` and `Promise.all` / `race` is, that you can use them on non-promises, which will just evaluate to the value itself. So this:

```
  await undefined;
  await Promise.all([ undefined, undefined ]);
```

will just run straight through, without raising any warnings (okay, not quite, it'll wait two microticks).

And thats what happens in your case. You are not `return`ing the promise you created from `checkImage`, therefore you basically call `Promise.all` on an array of `undefined`s.